# $\ell_{\infty}$ and the bounded approximation property

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I know from several references that the Banach space of bounded sequences, namely $\ell_{\infty}$, has the bounded approximation property. But I do not have a reference where this assertion is proven.

**So I would be very grateful if you can give me a reference for the result asserting that $\ell_{\infty}$ has the bounded approximation property ?**

**If you do not have a reference but you know how to do it, please provide me a sketch of your proof.**

I just recall here the definition of the approximation property.
We say that a Banach space $X$ has the *approximation property* (AP) if for every $\varepsilon>0$, for every compact set $K \subset X$, there exists a finite rank operator $T \in \mathcal B(X)$ such that $\|Tx-x\| \leq \varepsilon$ for every $x \in K$. Let $\lambda \geq 1$, if in the above definition T can always be chosen so that $\|T\|\leq \lambda$, then we say that $X$ has the *$\lambda$-bounded approximation property* ($\lambda$-(BAP)).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That $C(K)$-spaces have BAP follows from the existence of partitions of unity. See [this proof on p. 256](https://books.google.cz/books?id=n2TmBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA256&dq=%22approximation%20property%22%20%22partition%20of%20unity%22&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig_bnM8ezSAhUDJpoKHXWnDhoQ6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=%22approximation%20property%22%20%22partition%20of%20unity%22&f=false) of Köthe's *Topological Vector Spaces II*. Once you unwrap the proof, you will actually see that it shows that $C(K)$-spaces have 1-BAP.

Of course, $\ell_\infty=C(\beta \mathbb{N})$

Comment: Oh yes, that is true ! Thank you very much once again :).

Answer (score 1):

Not only that I think every subspace of $L_\infty$- space also has A.P.

Comment: Every separable Banach space is isomorphic to a subspace of $L_\infty$ ... so you claim every separable Banach space as A.P.?  My references do not agree with that.

Comment: yes. my mistake. What about $L_1$? Is every subspace of an $L_1$ space has the A.P.?